# Calculating the integral of a function in R2 which depends on whether or not x,y are rational/irrational

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Q is the rectangle $[0,1]^2$. f is the function going from Q to R where
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & x,y \text{ irrational} \\ 2 & x,y \text{ rational} \\ 1 & \text{else} \end{cases}$$

I need to calculate the integral $\int_{y\in[0,1]} \overline{\int}_{x\in[0,1]} f$

Now in the proof I've learned of Fubini's theorem, the upper integral should itself be integrable. However, in my calculation I'm ending up with
$\int_{y\in[0,1]} \left(\begin{cases}
1 & y\text{ irrational} \\
2 & y\text{ rational}
\end{cases}\right)$ which is not integrable.

I must be not correctly calculating the upper integral properly, but I can't seem to find where I'm going wrong. Here are the details of what I've done:

The upper integral has been defined as $\inf_{\text{partitions P of Q}}(U(f,P))$ where $U(f,P) = \sum_{\text{subrectangles R}\in P} M_R(f) vol(R)$

Where $M_R(f) = \sup(\{f(x) : x\in R\})$.

So, I fix a $y_0 \in [0,1]$, then for any subrectangle of any partition, there must be an uncountable number of irrationals in the subrectangle. And I know given any two irrationals there must exist a rational between them, thus there exists at least one rational for any subrectangle of any partition so $M_R(f) = \begin{cases}
1 & y_0\text{ irrational} \\
2 & y_0\text{ rational}
\end{cases}$

For any partition we know $M_R(f)$ is constant thus $U(f,P) = M_R(f) \sum_{R\in P} vol(R) = M_R(f) * vol(Q) = M_R(f)$.

That holds for any arbitrary partition thus $\overline{\int}_{x\in[0,1]} f = M_R(f) $

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Everything you've written looks correct to me.

Comment: For you to think:

Consider the function $g:\Bbb{R}\rightarrow\Bbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=0$ if $x\in\Bbb{Q}$ and $f(x)=1$ if  $x$ is not rational.

This function is continuous almost everywhere, that is, the set where $f(x)$ is discontinuous (that is, the set $\Bbb{Q})$ has (Lebesgue) measure zero, since $\Bbb{Q}$ is countable.

So, $g$ is integrable, and the integral of $g$ is equal to the integral of the constant function $1$.

Could thinking that way help you?

EDIT: Maybe I'm confusing the "integrable" meaning, since there are severous senses of integration. I'm using Riemann.

Comment: @MateusRocha I thought the function you're describing is _not_ Riemann integrable since the set of discontinuities is the irrationals which do not have measure zero. This is exactly my issue with the problem

Comment: Are you supposed to use the Riemann integral to solve this problem?

Comment: @Duncan I believe the book's definition of the integral is the Darboux integral, but a function is Darboux integrable iff it's Riemann integrable, so yes

Comment: Surely the answer to this should be zero

Comment: @Eli you could think about my $f$ as the function $1$, but with the set of its discontinuities as $\Bbb{Q}.$

Comment: @MateusRocha here's the issue though, it's not even integrable by definition. By the very argument I made to calculate the inner upper integral, the upper integral of the outside integral would be 2, but the lower integral would be 1. Hence since the lower and upper integrals are not equal, $M_R(f)$ is not Darboux integrable